# Flutter image not render / showing from internet using Image.network

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-image

I am facing a problem when working with `flutter-image`. I can render the image(s) from my device, but not the image(s) from the Internet!

I have to mention that I put the code in the *androidManifest* file to get permission for the internet as well.

But it does not work. Here is my code from the flutter documentation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = 'Web Images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Image.network(
          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I can't understand what the problem is! It doesn't show any errors or throw any exceptions. The image simply does not appear on the screen.

Is there anything I need to do to get the image rendered from the Internet or using url?

Comment: Image is showing when I run your code. I don't think the problem is in your code. Can you try 'flutter clean' in terminal and try again.

Comment: @Xuzan i will, if problem solves i will definitely inform here. May anything wrong with my AVD or pc. When i run flutter app, it always go previous state of the app and i need to restart app again !

Comment: I checked the code. Are you running the app in release mode i.e. `flutter run --release` so if yes then check in `AndroidManifest.xml` you might have misplaced internet permissions. Also, make sure that the internet is working on the device/emulator.

Comment: @AmolG, I figure out the problem. Somehow my app doesn't run on the emulator according to updated code, every time i hot restart it runs with previous state of code. So i need to restart or reload twice :( 
But why its happening ?
I tried uninstalling the app from emulator and then run again. But not work- i need to restart or reload twice to see the updated result according to my code. Strange !!!

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it seems working on both android emulator and iOS simulator.

***Android emulator:***
[image]

***iOS simulator:***
[image]

There was a [filed bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31548) regarding this issue.

Since some of the workaround have been mentioned in the the comments like checking the `INTERNET` is [enabled if you are running in a release mode](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31548#issuecomment-486367194).

> The default Flutter app template enables `INTERNET` permission for
> debug/profile modes (to support the Dart observatory) but not for
> release mode.

You could also try the following:

- Check the configuration of the DNS in your computer. It could be a possibility that it blocks the internet connection of your android emulator.
- Check the app with a different device (e.g. physical android device since its working in iOS), then if its working, it is something in your computer or internet to check on.

Also, other workarounds was also mentioned in the [filed bug comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31548#issuecomment-487290179):

> By the way there are two folders where AndroidManifest.xml appears my
> machine:
> **android/app/src/profile    android/app/src/debug**
>
> Make sure you have the permissions in both
>
> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.flloadimage">
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> Also Here somethings else to try see if phone has problem. Login to
> adb shell while device is launched (or plugged in) and ping the
> website.
>
> E.g. should look something like this
>
> ```
> ~$ adb shell
> generic_x86:/ $ ping picsum.photos
> PING picsum.photos (104.37.178.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 104.37.178.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=17.6 ms
> 64 bytes from 104.37.178.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=22.4 ms
> ^C
> --- picsum.photos ping statistics ---
> 6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5012ms
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.638/19.442/24.621/3.508 ms
> generic_x86:/  <press ctrl-d to exit to your prompt>
> ```
>
> Other ideas
>
> - Try on another wifi such as a cafe.
> - Do a flutter clean command to rebuild
> - Install on another computer